# 13th form of Hinokami Kagura

Tags: demon-slayer

Yoriichi mentioned to Tanjiro, in his narrative on his fight against Muzan, that he discovered the 13th form of the Hinokami Kagura while fighting Muzan (which scared Muzan pretty bad). However, it didn't seem like this 13th form was ever revealed afterwards, not even when it came to Tanjiro's turn to fight the demon boss. Does anyone know what this 13th form might be?